Reading database from Razor
Ok, I looked on StackOverflow and google and didn't found any solution.
What I read on web is that calling a Controller from a Razor page is BAD and it said we need to rethink our programming (as stated on Calling controller action method directly from Razor View)
Fine, I accept that. But I didn't find any other ways. Here the problem:

I got a .NET8 Web App Blazor/Razor (NOT WASM) with Microsoft Identity (Render is Server, Interactivity per page)
The same Web App also have API Controllers
One of theses controller can querying the Db for a webLink (stored) based on a stringId.

Example: StringId is E4A1 and it represent: https://Google.ca/
When querying the Api for "E4A1", it return "https://Google.ca/"


Querying the Controller (API) work fine, I need to be able to Query from a Razor page.

Here what I tried.

From Razor page, I added:

@inject ApplicationDbContext _DbContext


[Link] Model looks like this

public class LinkModel {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string StringId { get; set; } = "";

    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Url { get; set; } = "";
}


From Razor page @code section, I have a function trying to call

string strId = "E4A1";
LinkModel? objTable = await _DbContext.DbLinks.FirstOrDefaultAsync(w => w.StringId == strId);

Visual Studio complains that FirstOrDefaultAsync DOES NOT EXIST in that context.
So what I did is, inside the LinkController, I created a function:
public static class LinkFunctions {
    public static async Task<string> GetUrlX(ApplicationDbContext objDbContext, string strHex32Id) {
        LinkModel? objTable = await objDbContext.DbLinks.FirstOrDefaultAsync(w => w.StringId == strHex32Id);
        return objTable.Url;
    }
}

This is the exact same code but in the Controller
and I call it from my Razor page like this:
string strId = "E4A1";
string strUrl = await LinkFunctions.GetUrlX(_DbContext, strId);

which works...
Here the questions:

Why it isn't working from the Razor page (same code) ?
Why is it bad to call the controller from the Razor page
How do I fix it in a better way ?


For Blazor 8+, always state which render mode is being used.

"calling a Controller from a Razor page is BAD" ?? Add a reference to a source.

A razor View is not a Blazor page/component. And going through a Service is indeed better architecture but that's not a big deal.

I fail to see your point Henk. I'm using a Server Blazor App, the Razor is just the page model. The View component (Razor) is calling the database for Identity. When I try to call the Db for private table, it fail and the only workaround I found is calling the Db from a Controller. like I explained up here. And I don't know the solution. You're mentionning a Service, that is what my Controller is doing. If you're talking about IService, can you point me in to some working code so I can experiment ?

Is this blazor web assembly or blazor server?

The linked article is not about Blazor.

Make sure you have read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0#new-dbcontext-instances

as stated before it's a Web Blazor App with component. therefore, it is NOT WASM

Henk: Must I understand in your answer that it's OK to call a Controller from a Blazor component but it is NOT OK to call it from a Non Blazor Razop page ? Because that's what my primary question imply. So I'm confused. You're not giving a clear answer

Henk: Thanks for the article. I read it, but I fail to see what it give to the current question ?; The article mention the danger of using Singleton for DbContext because it is not thread safe. As per Microsoft code, the DbContext is used in Program.cs like this: builder.Services.AddDbContext(options => {
options.UseSqlServer(PublicVar.DbCnnString);
}); This way it's one instance for each load, right ?  I don't see how I used it badly under this circonstance. Plz explain your point.

I downloaded the git sample from the artcile... code is worth a thousand word. I'm not sure why they create that DbFactory, because DbContext is not a singleton, nor static in Microsoft code, therefore it's per session, wich make it impervious to thread issue (kind of unless 1 user session can generate thousand of fake call). But I'll try that method and come back here and explain what it give.

They use a DbFactory beacuse Blazor offers no usable DI scopes. Sadly that makes that Blazor requires different Repositories from most other platforms. One more reason to use a Web API.
